# angular-ui-tree collapse/expand not working

Tags: angularjs

I try to use angular-ui-tree, but collapse not working. I use example from their github with minor changes, but id did not help.

My example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MIMQ0GWnhQnZ1AhhKzo5?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="tCtrl">
<div class="tree">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3>Basic Example</h3>
      <button ng-click="expandAll()">Expand all</button>
      <button ng-click="collapseAll()">Collapse all</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div ui-tree="" id="tree-root">
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="listss">
          <li ng-repeat="t in listss" ui-tree-node="">
            <div ui-tree-handle="" class="tree-node tree-node-content">
              <button data-nodrag="" ng-click="toggle(this)">saad</button>
              {{t.name}}
            </div>
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="t.list" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
              <li ng-repeat="s in t.list" ui-tree-node="">
                <div ui-tree-handle="" class="tree-node tree-node-content">
                  <button ng-click="toggle(this)">sad</button>
                  {{s.name}}
                </div>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You miss CSS class. Please, insert your file CSS.

```
.hidden {    
    display: none!important;    
    visibility: hidden!important;
}
```

Github use bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things:

1. add some options from in your controller:

   `$scope.treeOptions = {
                   accept: function (sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {
                       return false;
                   },
               };`

2.get the treeview:

`var getRootNodesScope = function () {
                    return angular.element(document.getElementById("tree-root")).scope();
                };`

3. add the collapse / expand functions to your controller:

`$scope.collapseAll = function () {
                    var scope = getRootNodesScope();
                    scope.collapseAll();
                };
                $scope.expandAll = function () {
                    var scope = getRootNodesScope();
                    scope.expandAll();
                };`

4. Replace the following line :`<div ui-tree="" id="tree-root">`
   with  `div ui-tree="treeOptions>"`

5.Optional: Place the id="tree-root" on your `<ol>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this solution dont work for me. I gave an info 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' - function always call itself. when i change name of function - it dont find function - 'scope.collapseAll is not a function'